# How to set Scroll position near to mat row in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, uiscrollview, angular-material-table

I have more than 20 records loaded to angular material table. When I click one row it navigates to a page. And when I hit back button it return to table page. The problem is when I click on last row of the table, the scroll position goes to the top. **I just want to set scroll position near to the clicked row.**

How do I achieve that and refer code in below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-router-mra2ke?file=src/app/plain/plain.component.ts

Comment: You mean in new page? or when you click to `back` button?

Comment: When clicked on back button , scroll position should set  nearest to clicked row in table page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to singleton service to keep the current position:

(Note we also can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` **But** using singleton service is highly recommended and it's better that using other way!)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
  elementClickedId:any;
}
```

And also you need to set id for your td:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" id={{element.position}}>{{ element.position }}</td>
```

And use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit` to make sure after completion of rendering your table, you set the scroll.

Here is working sample I've created for you: [StackBlitzForked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-router-r4skn2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fplain%2Fplain.component.ts)

Comment: @Sanjana Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Is there any other way instead of using document.getElementById ?? @Alireza Ahmadi

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do two things to make the existing code work:

- Component variables are lost when the component is destroyed. So instead of using the component variable to store the current position use browser storages like `sessionStorage`/`localStorage` or use a `variable from shared service` and set `id` to the rows. For example you can do something like:

```
  get elementClickedId() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('elementClickedId');
  }

  set elementClickedId(id) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('elementClickedId', id);
  }
```

Set id within your html:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [id]="element.position">
   {{ element.position }}
</td>
```

- When you are trying to do document.getElementById the view is not initialized, so it's not being auto scrolled. So instead of calling `moveToSection` in `ngOnInit`, do it in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-router-eo6wnt?file=src/app/plain/plain.component.ts

**PS: Angular comes with navigation config [scrollPositionRestoration](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration) that helps in achieving this. But unfortunately it doesn't work all the time, there's a defect for it - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547**